# Forwarding only the root of a subdomain to a folder in the main domain (mod_rewrite)

Tags: mod-rewrite

I think I'm misunderstanding some fundamental thing here, as this is my first time using `mod_rewrite`.

I would like the following:

```
blog.example.com
blog.example.com/
blog.example.com/index.php
```

to redirect to:

```
example.com/blog
```

However, I would like all other cases to do nothing, e.g.

```
blog.example.com/foobar
blog.example.com/wp-admin
blog.example.com/wp-admin.php
```

This is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =blog.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^|/|index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.example\.com/blog [QSA,L]
```

I have tried many variants but each time either all requests redirect, or none redirect, so `mod_rewrite` is definitely doing something, just not what I want.

I have skimmed through [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) for anything relevant, but I think the issue is more that I'm missing some subtle fact due to inexperience. Would someone kindly point out my error? I know we don't need yet another `mod_rewrite` question on SO but I'm really struggling with this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the one you posted is 'all redirects' or 'none redirects' ?

Comment: @Nelson - all requests redirect for the above example :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =blog.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ http://www.example.com/blog [QSA,R,L]
```

Some basic points:

1. The second part of the rewrite rule is not a regular expression, so periods do not need to be escaped there.
2. I was not familiar with the =String option for RewriteCond.  Thank you for teaching me something today (I was worried when I did not see a regex there but that should be fine)!  I would add [NC] here since it will help match both lowercase and uppercase versions of your domain.
3. None of this will work unless your virtual host includes the blog.example.com subdomain as a proper alias, and DNS is set up for that subdomain.

Comment: edited answer to reflect that =String is a valid form of RewriteCond

Comment: That worked! Responses to your points. (1) Understood, thanks. (2) Actually, I think the ``=`` does literal (non-regex) matching. I'm able to use ``=blog.globalcitizenstravel.com`` okay, at least. (3) I'm not sure how to check this but it's working! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Oh, you edited your answer while I was typing my comment. Well, I didn't know about ``[NC]`` so thanks for that too!